# ASP.NET Core App not being able to decrypt protected data persisted to the registry

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-protection

I'm using DataProtection on .NET5 to protect the key I'm using JWTs my app generates. Keys are written at installation by launching the .exe version of my app with special parameters - it takes the key, protects it, and writes it to a file. When the web app then starts up on IIS, it unprotects the content of that file as part of the JWT issuing process.

Here's what happens when I launch the exe

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection
    .AddDataProtection(o => o.ApplicationDiscriminator = applicationDiscriminator);
    .SetApplicationName(appName)
    .PersistKeysToRegistry(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(registryLocation, true));
    
var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var dataProtectionProvider = services.GetService<IDataProtectionProvider>();
var protector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(appName);    
var protectedSecret = protector.Protect(plaintextKey);
//write content to a file
```

I Startup.cs / `ConfigureServices`, I set up data protection for DI as follows

```
services
    .AddDataProtection(o => { o.ApplicationDiscriminator = applicationDiscriminator; })
    .SetApplicationName(appName)
    .PersistKeysToRegistry(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(registryLocation, true));
```

and then when the app is up and running, I get the keys as follows

```
public class KeyReader
{
    private IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider;

    public KeyReader(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider) 
    {
        this.dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider;
    }
    
    public String ReadKey(string fileName)
    {
        var fileContent = File.ReadAll(fileName);
        return dataProtectionProvider.Unprotect(fileContent)
    }
}
```

Now, when my app is started in the IIS context (it runs on an App Pool that runs under the same user identity as I launched the .exe when protecting the key), it cannot Unprotect the file content.

The precise error I'm getting is this `The provided payload cannot be decrypted because it was not protected with this protection provider.`

If I change the code to use `PersistKeysToFileSystem` (haven't tried also DAPI protecting them), it works. So what's different?

I also tried not using the the `PersistKeysTo..` options, in which case I'm getting
`The key {some guid here} was not found in the key ring.` (of course for every test I'm regenerating the file where I'm saving the key to, and always doing that operation under the same account as the app pool account). Of course I also ran `Provision-AutoGenKeys.ps1` for the test without `PersistKeysTo...`, but it just doesn't take. In the scenario without manual key persistence, if I look at debug logs for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` that its getting the key material from another location when I launch it as an exe versus when the app runs on IIS (which gave me the idea to try specifying my own key persistence).

Any ideas on how I can make this work on either using the registry, or ideally not having to specify manual key persistence at all?

Comment: i think it is because you use one user to encrypt, but another(IIS?) to decrypt.

Comment: Actually, no. the App pool on IIS runs on the same account as the account where I wrote the data to protect. That's the most obvious way this can go wrong, but I've covered that case. The second obvious problem source - purpose being set to the path of the file (IIS will not run the exe, but the dll, hence me setting a common `ApplicationDiscriminator`.)

If it were about users, then file system wouldn't work either.. not every user has access to the path I provide in `PersistKeysToFileSystem`

Comment: So I found an important clue: I knew we had this working just fine in one of our labs. When I compared all the settings, I found that the app pool where it used to work, it hat `Load User Profile` set to true in the advanced App Pool settings. Systems where it doesn't work (without `PersistKeyTo...` ) had this to false. I guess that's the missing link.